# how to solve the ODE G(s(t))=s'(t)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, systems-of-equations

Consider the following system

$$G(s(t))=s'(t),\ $$

$$(G(U(t))-G(W(t)),U(t)-W(t))_{2}\le0$$
then $||U(t)-W(t)||^2$ is a decreasing function

Comment: Take its derivative and you get the expression which is given to be non-positive (after the parentheses get fixed).

Comment: can you explain me better : Take its derivative and you get the expression which is given to be non-positive.

Comment: The derivative of $\left\|A(t)\right\|^2$ is $2(A'(t),A(t))$. Now use that $G(U(t))=U'(t)$ and $G(W(t))=W'(t)$ and you are done.

Comment: yes this was my idea but i was in doubt if it was true or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U$ and $W$ be two solutions. Then subtracting corresponding equations you get 
$G(U)-G(W)=U'-W'$ and takin $L^2 $ inner product of this equation with $U-W$ you have
$(G(U)-G(W), U-W)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{dt}\|U-W\|^2$. Using the hypothesis you get the result.

Comment: $\frac{d}{dt}||U-V||^2 \le 0 $ this mean that my solution is decreasing yes?

Comment: it is not for the solution just $L^2$ norm of difference of solutions.

Comment: yes i mean the norm of the diffrence is decreasing

Comment: Be sure it is decreasing (or non increasing) you have just a function whose derivative is negative (or non positive) is there a  trouble?

Comment: maybe im confused a little bit but the derivate of a function f <0 doesn't that mean that my f is decreasing? thank for your help

Comment: no doubt it is so, you're welcome

Comment: so this proove my problem.